# matlab curve fitting with sub-polynomial

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am wondering how do I fit three points `x = ([0.42 0.64 0.96])` and
`y = ([4.2 5.1 6.0])` with y = k*x^(0.88)?

I tried `[p,S,mu] = polyfit(x,y,0.88);` but MATLAB says only power in integer numbers are accepted. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The idea is I know these three points should follow the curve based on some theory, so I want to plot it to convince myself. Also, I'd like to do curve fitting because I don't know what `k` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `lsqnonlin` ?

You could try

```
model = @(x,k) (k*x.^0.88);
resVec = @(k) (y(:) - model(x(:),k));
k_start = 1;
k_opt = lsqnonlin(resVec,k_start);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with adding a constant to your model you can do:

```
[p,S,mu] = polyfit(x.^(0.88),y,1);
```

then you'll have `y` approximated by `p(2)*x.^(0.88)+p(1)` (minimizing the sum of the squares of the errors)